# How do I Bulk Delete all of my YouTube Comments and Replies?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to bulk delete all my YouTube comments without restarting my channel or deleting anything else?

I couldn't really find a good solution anywhere else.

Comment: There is no quick, easy, or convenient way to bulk delete all YouTube comments, and there's definitely no way to mass-delete comments with any sort of useful control, like all comments you've made to a specific channel or all comments you've made with certain words. Google wants to KEEP all data, not let you remove data, and they want themselves to have all of the control, not let others have any control. ¬_¬

Comment: I had the need to
a) start deleting from the oldest comment
b) and delete in batch quantities
The script that I came up with is publicly accessible at https://gist.github.com/cprima/2f7ea8e353c18a666506021c85e9773d

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to the [YouTube Advanced Account Settings](https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced) page:

1. Press delete channel.
2. Expand the "I want to hide my channel" section.
3. Check everything and press the "HIDE MY CHANNEL" button.

You may need to wait a little before YouTube deletes your comments. You can check that all of your comments are delete here: [Comments History](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history)

If necessary, you can go to your channel page (or [this](https://www.youtube.com/create_channel)) to un-hide it (it will ask you for you name again). Doing this will also private your subscriptions, videos, and playlists, but you can set them to public as needed.

NOTE: I actually found this myself, though it's identical to this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJVi4TQh1bE) and this [Technicles article](http://technicles.com/mass-delete-youtube-comments-solved-2017/).

Comment: Thank you!  I was going through my comment history and found an endless stream of comments from when I was young.  Christ, what have I done...

Comment: Everything you've ever said anywhere in any context, will be taken out of context and used against you in a court of law.  This is basically in the 95 pages of legalese in the google EULA.  Which isn't necessarily a bad thing, because if you go onto commit crime, we'll have a blow by blow snapshot of everything that lead up to those conditions.  Soon after, we'll be able to `rm -rf ` you as the crime is carried out, rather than after you were caught doing the crime.

Comment: If you know a bit of JS, you can run this in the console (replace the class name with the button one). ```const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe")

for (index = 1; index < elements.length; index++) {
 elements[index].click();
}``` I can't answer caues I don't have enough rep...

Comment: "I want to hide my channel" doesn't appear to be an option on that page anymore. The options are to hide content or permanently delete all my content.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to **bulk** delete, without restarting your channel.

This answer will therefore specifically focus on how to **delete** comments, which is a painful way of removing all your content

---

**You can only delete certain comments**

- You can delete comments that you've made on other people's videos.
- You can delete comments that others have made on your videos.
- You can remove comments that others have made by reporting them. If the comment gets enough votes, it will be removed.
- You cannot delete multiple comments at once.
- You cannot delete comments made before YouTube was bought by Google (October 2006).

---

**How to delete**

1. Sign in
2. Open the Watch page for the video you left the comment on
3. Click the "All comments" link
4. Find the comment you want to delete.
5. Click the small triangle on the right side of the comment
6. Click "Remove"

   - Ensure that you are logged in with the correct channel if you don't see the "Remove" option.

Comment: It's easier just to go to your History, then click Comment history, and delete from that page.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy now. Go Here:

https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history

It is good practice to first edit the comment, to something null, before deleting it. The reason for this, is that this has a greater chance to delete anything that was posted, in case deleted comments are saved in their database. 
Thus, if the comment is edited first, that saved comment may only reflect the most recent edit.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The link just shows history of videos I've commented on. It doesn't provide a way to bulk delete comments.

Comment: @user1751825 It does answer, given that you can click, and delete. With a bit of javascript, everything can be deleted in bulk.

Comment: I had previously tried the link from mobile, where the behaviour is quite different. I can see that in desktop mode is does indeed list the comments directly. Not quite deleting in bulk, but helpful nontheless. I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: ```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function d() {
  var i=0;
  document.body.querySelectorAll('.VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe.yHy1rc.eT1oJ').forEach(async (e) => {
    await sleep(1000 * i++);
    e.click();
  });
}

d();
```

Replace the selector of the <button> element representing the delete (X) button. It waits a second in between each click. You may have to run it multiple times because the page autoloads more and those don't exist in the DOM at the time this is run.

Comment: @StevenLinn great solution. Still works. Didn't even have to change the class names. Thanks!

Comment: This helps [...document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSNAME_OF_BUTTON')].forEach((el, i) => setTimeout(() => el.click(), 2000 * i));

Comment: `It is good practice to first edit the comment, to something null, before deleting it. The reason for this, is that this has a greater chance to delete anything that was posted, in case deleted comments are saved in their database. Thus, if the comment is edited first, that saved comment may only reflect the most recent edit.` I used to advise the same thing, but Big Tech uses RCS/VCS to save EVERYTHING, including edits, so you can NEVER delete content, they'll keep it **FOREVER**. The only way to be sure they don't keep your data is to never post it in the first place.

Comment: That said, yes, replace data with dummy-data before deleting, just in case. However, be careful in this case because having a lot of duplicate comments might trigger YT's (feckless ) anti-spam system and suspend your entire Google account for "spam". 

Comment: @Synetech Perhaps ironically then the best thing to do would then to edit your comments to look like spam, so you will be put on a `best to probably ignore list`